# Java records in open-api generator

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi-generator

Can I generate immutable models with open api generator without changing the mustache templates? My first thought was that the generator could be configured to generate Java records but I can't find any information on how to do this. I've also included the @Value lombok annotation in the generator config but setters are still generated due to the caveat that I have to modify the mustache templates to omit setters which is not currently an option.

Comment: You can't, at least using the open-api generator from Spring, you should find a external library for that generation purpose, I could recommend you https://github.com/sngular/scs-multiapi-plugin, I am not sure if they support inmutable models, but I am sure they could add it.

Comment: It's not possible, an issue has been opened a couple of years ago to track down the issue: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/10490